# Converting SSH model into fourier-space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, momentum, fourier-transform, second-quantization

In SSH model hopping between two sites is staggered i.e. hopping strength between site-1 and site-2 is (let's say) $J$ and between site-2 and site-3 is $J'$ and between site-3 and site-4 is again $J$ and so on. SSH Hamiltonian can be written as:
$$H=\sum_{n=1}^{L/2}(Jc_{2n-1}^\dagger c_{2n}+J'c_{2n}^\dagger c_{2n+1}+h.c.)$$
Where $c_i^\dagger$ and $c_i$ are creation and annihilation operators respectively and $L$ are total number of sites. I am trying to write this Hamiltonian in k-space. For that one can take fourier transform of creation and annihilation operators as following:
$$c_n^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_k c_{k}^{\dagger} e^{ikR_n} \\c_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_k c_{k}^{} e^{-ikR_n}$$
Where $R_n $ is position of $nth$ particle in 1D discrete real space. Using these transformations 1st term of Hamiltonian in k-space can be written as: 
$$H(k)_{1st}=J\sum_{k,k'}\sum_{n=1}^{L/2} \frac{e^{ik(R_{2n-1})}}{\sqrt{L}}\frac{e^{-ik'R_{2n}}}{\sqrt{L}}c_k^\dagger c_{k'}$$
As distance between two sites is equal so we can write it as:
$$H(k)_{1st}=J\sum_{k,k'}\sum_{n=1}^{L/2}\frac{e^{iR_{2n}(k-k')}}{L}e^{ik}c_k^\dagger c_{k'}$$
Normally when we are taking equal hopping strength between two sites we have Hamiltonian of kind $H_{kin}=t\sum_{n=1}^L c_i^\dagger c_{i+1}$ which after transforming into k-space gives a term of kind $\sum_{n=1}^L e^{iR_n(k-k')}$ that we put equal to $L\delta_{k,k'}$ but here in my $H(k)_{1st}$ I have term which have $R_{2n}$ and summation is over $L/2$ instead of $R_{n}$ and $L$ respectively.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Try thinking in terms of lumping two adjacent sites into a single unit cell. Will lead to simple hopping Hamiltonian in matrix form.

Comment: Please define $R_n$. Without a definition, it's really hard to answer this question.

Comment: $R_n $ is position of $nth $ particle in 1D discrete real space.

Comment: You can look at http://phyx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TI/Lecture%20notes/1.html to find precisely same problem being treated.

Comment: Are you sure about the second term? Isn't it $J'c_{2n}^{\dagger} c_{2n+1}$ ?

Comment: @confused thank you so much but I wanted to solve it like this way for better understanding.

Comment: @Matteo thank you for your suggestion. It was $c_{2n}^\dagger$.